# SQL query to select colors not like color variants

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have searched for a better way to do this, but haven't found anything that works in my specific situation. This is in SQLite.

I have the following query:

```
select color1, color2 
from table
where color1 = 'red'
  and color2 not like '%red%' 
  and color2 not like '%scarlet%' 
  and color2 not like '%cherry%'
```

In other words, I'm trying to select colors that don't match known color variants. I have to use `like` because this is free-form text.

My query works fine, but it becomes unwieldy as I add more variants to it. I tried putting the variants in another table and using a subquery, like so:

```
select color1, color2 
from table
where color1 = 'red'
  and color2 not like '%' || (select color_alias from color where color = 
'red') || '%'
```

However, the like statement only evaluates the first record returned by the subquery.

Does anyone know of a way to include the color variants in a lookup table and still use the `like` operator?

Comment: If you really want to solve this problem, you should have another table with a base color and variant column, for each variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT color1, color2
FROM   mytable
WHERE  color1 = 'red' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   colors
                   WHERE  color = 'red' AND 
                          color LIKE '%' || color2 || '%')
```